# Chart.js - equal distance between vertical grid lines

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart.js in one of my project and I love it, but it cannot find a setting  for forcing the same distance between all vertical grid lines. The case is when the last value on X is distant from the previous more than the average. Is there an option to change that so all the lines are at the same distance from another?[image]